# On the equivalence of two definitions of null sets

Tags: measure-theory

I am currently reading the lecture notes of two different professors and I would like to verify/understand that their definitions of null sets are equivalent.

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space and $N\subset X$. $N$ is called a null set with respect to $\mu$ if...

> **Definition 1.**
>
> \begin{equation} \exists N'\in\Sigma:\mu(N')=0\land N\subset N'
> \end{equation}
>
> **Definition 2.** \begin{equation} \inf\big\{\mu(A):A\in\Sigma\land N\subset A\big\}=0 \end{equation}

Thus, I need to verify the following equivalence:
\begin{equation}
\exists N'\in\Sigma:\mu(N')=0\land N\subset N'\Leftrightarrow
\inf\big\{\mu(A):A\in\Sigma\land N\subset A\big\}=0
\end{equation}
The LHS clearly implies the RHS, but the converse is not clear. Here is my attempt. Suppose that the infimum is zero, then there is some $A_n\in\Sigma$ s.t. $N\subset A_n$ and $\mu(A_n)\leq\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. If $\mu(\cap_{n=1}^\infty A_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(A_n)$, this would complete proof, but is this actually true for an arbitrary measure?

Comment: Hint: What can you say if $\mu(\cap_{n=1}^\infty A_n) = s > 0$?

Comment: @aschepler Then $s\leq \mu(A_n)$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$, which is a contradiction :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for $\mu(\cap_{n=1}^\infty A_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(A_n)$

$\mu (\bigcap_n A_n)\leq \frac  1n$ for all $n$ so $\mu (\bigcap_n A_n)=0$ even if $\mu$ is an infinite measure.

Comment: By contradiction?

Comment: $\bigcap_n A_n \subset A_m$ for any $m$ and this implies that $\mu (\bigcap_n A_n) \leq \frac 1 m$. @Filippo

Comment: As far as I understand the proof boils down to the following fact: If $0\leq x$ and $x\leq \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$, then $x=0$. This can only be proven by contradiction, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  That is a basic fact about  real numbers and one doesn't give such details in Measure Theory (which comes after a full course in Calculus). @Filippo